# Sending an argument with an ethers contract object

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, ethers.js

I'm trying to interface with my tested (in Remix) and working contract in a browser now but cannot understand how to send additional arguments with a payable function.

I need to pass an argument `userTeamChosen` with a `appendUserBet()` function which I both set the values for through html forms but get this error **Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit** and have no idea whether im sending the argument correctly or not.

index.html:

```html
<body>
  <label for="fund">ETH Amount</label>
  <input id="ethAmount" placeholder="0.1" />
  <input id="betTeam" placeholder="Team name" />
  <button type="button" id="appendBetButton"> appendBetButton </button>
</body>

<script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
```

smart contract function:

```
    function appendUserBet(string memory userTeamChosen) public payable {
        uint256 minimumFee = 1 * 10**17 wei;
        userList.push(payable(msg.sender));
        require(msg.value >= minimumFee);
        fee = msg.value;
        userStructs[msg.sender].betAmount += msg.value;
        userStructs[msg.sender].teamChosen = userTeamChosen;
    }
```

and this is where I interact with it in index.js:

```js
async function appendUserBet() {
    const ethAmount = document.getElementById("ethAmount").value
    console.log(`Funding with ${ethAmount}...`)
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer)
        try {
            const transactionResponse = await contract.appendUserBet({
                value: ethers.utils.parseEther(ethAmount), userTeamChosen: "sab", gasLimit: 50000
            })
            await listenForTransactionMine(transactionResponse, provider)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    } else {
        appendBetButton.innerHTML = "Please install MetaMask"
    }
}
```

Can somebody please let me know how to add the needed string argument to a payable function in a js interface with ethers?

Thanks alot for your time in advance!

Comment: have you tried with the gas limit higher?

Comment: yep, tried adding 5 zeros at the end, doesnt help :(

Comment: Are you using hardhat by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are passing the argument to the smart contract in the wrong way.

The documentation states that you have to pass the arguments before you pass the overrides https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-functionsSend.

So the call according to this should look like this:

```
await contract.appendUserBet(
   "sab",
   {
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther(ethAmount), gasLimit: 50000
   }
)
```

You might be able to omit the `gasLimit` override if this solves your issue.

Comment: god bless your soul, this solved my problem :)